# я хочу чтобы мой бот отправлял сообщение в определенный канал по названию

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

кто нибудь может подсказать пожалуйста?

Comment: Эту информацию можно найти тут https://core.telegram.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
channel_to_delete = list(filter(lambda channel: channel.name == "название", ctx.guild.text_channels))[0]
```